# Laravel 4 and AngularJS - clean URL's with routing

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-4

I'm new to AngularJS and having a hard time getting it to work smoothly with Laravel. I am trying to create a back-end application for a website and want the routes prefixed with '/admin' to all be managed by AngularJS without the hash in the URL.

### Laravel's Back-end

**Routes**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', function() {
        return View::make('backend/dashboard');
    });
});
```

**View - dashboard.blade.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="glenn">
<head>
    <title>Laravel and Angular Together</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <base href="/admin">

    <script src="vendor/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### AngularJS Front-end

**app.js**

```
var glenn = angular.module('glenn', ['ngRoute']);

glenn.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/test', {
            templateUrl: 'test.html',
            controller: 'TestController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

glenn.controller('TestController', function($scope) {

});
```

Problem: when I direct the browsers url to admin/test, then I receive Laravel's `NotFoundHttpException` because Laravel is trying to take over the routes that I want Angular to take care of...how can I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since angular will be handling all the routing for admin (and you won't be specifying any further routing in Laravel), you can probably do without the prefix.

Try:

```
Route::get('admin{angular}', function () {
    return View::make('backend/dashboard');
})->where('angular', '.*');
```

Instead of:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', function() {
        return View::make('backend/dashboard');
    });
});
```

This should catch all routes that begin with admin, which is what I believe you want.

Answer (score 1):

On a related note:

If you were creating an Angular + Laravel web app where you wanted *all* routing to be handled by AngularJS you can specify a 'catch-all' route within Laravel to avoid the `NotFoundHttpException` error:

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return View::make('backend/dashboard'); // this should match your index route
});
```